# How do I search for contacts with "not empty" multiple records field?

Tags: custom-fields, search, search-builder

today I realized that the search builder does not provide access to custom multiple-record-fields. Thus I'm wondering how it's possible to search for contacts having at least one record of such field.

Any ideas?

Thanx in advance // nielo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a stock installation of Civi 4.6, I don't think this is possible.  However, this is possible in Civi 4.7: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16137

This is a very simple patch, so if you want this functionality today, check this out: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/5435/files

Comment: Thanks a lot, jon. Can't believe how tiny this changeset is.